SAP S4 HANA Cloud Business User Retrival
how can I collect data of all business users in SAP S/4HANA Cloud using APIs/SDK etc.
I used SAP JCo (Java Connector) for collecting data from SAP ECC and SAP S/4HANA On premise.
Any code reference/snippet will be helpful.
Thanks
